# Painting Rows based on Cells' Values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Let's say I have a spreadsheet with ten rows (numbered 1 to 10) and ten columns 
(represented alphabetically A through J). Here's what I'm trying to do:

Firstly, I want a given row to be painted green entirely whenever the following conditions are met within the cells of that row:

- Cell E has the value "ALPHA"

**AND**

- Cell F has the value "BETA"

**AND**

- Cell G has the values "GAMMA" **OR** "DELTA"

Furthermore, I want blank cells to remain white, meaning that the coloring should be applied exclusively to cells that have any values (whatsoever) in them.

Finally, I want that this conditional formatting would be applied to my ENTIRE spreadsheet, and will continue to be applied automatically as I go and expand my spreadsheet with new columns and rows.

The question is: how do I achieve this?

EDIT: I believe my question is different than the one it was marked a duplicate of. While the other question revolves around the coloring of a CELL based on the value of ANOTHER cell, what I'm trying to do is to color whole rows based on the presence of certain values in different cells, with some added complexities such as varying values within a cell that match the same rule; different coloring for different rules; and leaving blank cells white even if they belong to a painted row.

And also, there's no mention in that question of how to apply the rules automatically to an expanding sheet as new rows and columns are added.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't asked a question and you haven't stated what you've already tried.

Comment: Your suggested edit improved it, but please also state what you already tried.

Comment: (1) You and I seem to have different definitions of the word “entirely”.  You say, “I want a given row to be painted green *entirely* whenever the following conditions are met …” — but the next full paragraph indicates that you want *only* the non-blank cells to be colored.  (2) You say, “… what I'm trying to do is … different coloring for different rules ….”  I don’t see that anywhere in your actual question.  (3) Excel’s windows are littered with `?` icons, which bring up Help.  Please use it.

Comment: You are correct. I'll try to explain myself better. 1) When I wrote the former paragraph I was thinking about the vast majority of the rows in my sheet, which do not contain any blank cells. In conclusion, I could say that what I'm trying to do is paint every cell in a given sheet, based on values in more than one sheet - but leave blank cells blank. That is until I fill them with text and they are painted with appropriate color based on the conditional formatting. 2) This is something I though I'll achieve myself when I'll have a working base formula, that I'll adjust accordingly.

Comment: Hi folks, I really need your help. Here is formula I've been working on, with no results. `code`=AND($D31="ALPHA", $E31="BETA", $F31=100%, $G31="GAMMA").